# Eclipse java editor bar

Tags: eclipse

There is a bar on the top of java editor in eclipse showing current project, package, class and method.
How could I turn it on / of ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is called Breadcrumb. Press Alt+shift+B.